groups faild with equal height group in tcolorbox, and strange behavior of breakable in tcbraster
What I want is a tcolorbox raster. And I found some confusion:
CASE1: I firstly use the equal height group=tmp and wrapped them by begingroup and endgroup, however it seemed that something is global, and different raster share the same namespace as below, how to tune it?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\NewDocumentCommand{\contrastenv}{O{}mO{}m}{%
    \begingroup
    \par\vspace*{1ex}\noindent
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={#1},equal height group=tmp,breakable]
            #2
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={#3},equal height group=tmp,breakable]
            #4
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{minipage}
    \par\vspace*{1ex}
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[8]
    \contrastenv[AAA]{%
        This is a short short short short short short short short text.
    }[BBB]{
        This is a long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text.
    }
    \lipsum[8]
    \contrastenv[Elec.]{%
        $F=k\frac{Qq}{r^2}r_0$ \\
        $E=\frac{F}{q}$
    }[Magn.]{
        $F=qv\times B$
    }
\end{document}



CASE2: The breakable will change the raster, if I want to change
make the raster breakable, how can I achieve that?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height,]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=A]This is a short text.\end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=B]This is a long long long long long long long long long long text.\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=A,breakable]This is a short text.\end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=B,breakable]This is a long long long long long long long long long long text.\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

Actually it is the breakable change cause the strange behavior, didn't make the raster columns=2.

Then I hopes that the raster could be breakable and the test.

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=A,breakable]\lipsum[2]\end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=B,breakable]\lipsum[3]\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

What I want is two breakable tcb positioned in raster, but the breakable here seems not work.

\end{document}


update: I found some comment here about the breakable raster, it's a good question here: "I doubt very much that you can use it with breakable". However I want to clearify the usage cases of my \contrastenv. Say that I want to show two word-lists side by side(one for American and one for British) to illustrate their difference, at the same time the list is too-long, so the requirement of breakable raster appeared. I will consult the magazine library later as the advice.

You are using the same id everywhere. The behavior is not strange. It is as per the documentation.

Please ask separate questions for separate problems.

Your second case also seems to produce correct output. In fact, I don't see any contrast except the line break which is caused by the breakable key. Removing breakable yields identical results.

Sorry, I put them together just because they are in the same exploration(I will seperate them apart next time), the environment is used to contrast some similar conception in the article. And I will also try mt best to make the mwe the smallest.

Yes, you said right, the breakable is what I want to test for the breakable case, and I forgot to delete it.

No problem. Hope the answer clarifies your doubt regarding the unexpected "global" effect.

Don't use \ for line-breaking. It's a very bad practice. Use blank lines instead.

Thanks to your advice, but you mention that "Your second case also seems to produce correct output", I found that the strange case is caused by the breakable accidentally. I will implement the original question.

I don't know what the exact use-case is, but following the documentation of equal height group correctly can give you fair results without \begingroup and \endgroup. Have a careful look at the documentation:

(The box added by me).
What this means is you can use different ids and get boxes of different heights. But you are using the same id, i.e., tmp as the same code is repeated using your definition of \contrastenv. The following, on the other hand, works:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\NewDocumentCommand{ \contrastenv }{ O{} +m O{} +m }{%
  \par\vspace*{1ex}\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.48\textwidth}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        breakable,%
        title               = {#1},%
        equal height group  = {#1}%
      ]%
      #2%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{.48\textwidth}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        breakable,%
        title               = {#3},%
        equal height group  = {#1}%
      ]%
      #4%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\vspace*{1ex}%
}
\begin{document}
\contrastenv[%
  AAA%
]{%
  hello%
}[%
  BBB%
]{%
  Five lines text%

  Five lines text%

  Five lines text%

  Five lines text%

  Five lines text%
}

\contrastenv[%
  CCC%
]{%
  $a=b$%
  
  $c=d$%
}[%
  DDD%
]{%
  $a=b$%
}
\end{document}



Thanks,change the title as the id worked, however, in my \contrastenv, the title(i.e. #1) is optional, I think it may share the same id with two rasters both without title parameter?

Hmm, that's a different problem. I had thought about it, but here in this answer I just wanted to show you the actual problem. What is even more problematic is you may want to have some TeX-code in title, e.g., $a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$. This may fail (not tested though). One simple (and fast) solution is to add another argument for adding different ids, but I think raster equal height already does what you want, so better to go with it. I know another way to solve it with equal height group, but that would just be like reinventing the wheel given the presence of raster equal height.

I got your point. I knew that adding another key named id actually works, but thinking as the command user, this key is shouldn't be provided by user (just the command's requirement but not the user's, I hope I delivered it clearly) Another key like id seems a little superfluous and unfriendly to user.

@Explorer I agree with you, but also consider that asking the user to set the key gives them more control. Imagine a case where they want a box of a height that they had used earlier. Using their own defined keys can be an advantage here. Anyway, I still believe that using raster equal height instead of equal height group is the way to go if the you need automatic height processing. If there is something because of which you need to use equal height group, then some additional programming will be needed. I can show you a way, but I believe it will unnecessarily slow down your processing.

The usage of raster equal height is more elegant, and we actually avoid reinventing the wheel. Thanks! @Niranjan

@Explorer use some counter to  generate ids contrastenv1, contrastenv2, etc.

@UlrikeFischer Oh, it actually a good idea to do that. thanks!
